# zend acl for list of records to view

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

I've got a list of trades (lets say some records) made by different users in my Zend framework based application.

I want to allow users to view only their trades, and if they try to view another user's trade by changing the url by themselves. They would get a message that they don't have permission to view or change anything.

Kindly help me figure out how can I do this using Zend, ACL, or another better way.

Comment: Do you store you trades(records) in the database?

Comment: Yes I do store them in DB!

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I wouldn't use ACL for restricting access to the list of trades. Instead in controller's action, which get list of trades and pass them to the view, I would check who is owner of each list and compare this owner with a logged in user.